# How can I crop the PDF page

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

Can any one help me that how can I cut the PDF page like as Acrobat professional?

Comment: What PDF library are you using?

Comment: i m using i textsharp library but there is no such information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [snippet](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.dotnet.itextsharp.general/2008-09/msg00080.html) might help you:

```
public static void CropDocument(string file, string oldchar, string repChar)
{
    int pageNumber = 1;
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
        Globals.fX, Globals.fY, 
        Globals.fWidth, Globals.fHeight);
    Document document = new Document(size);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document,
        new FileStream(file.Replace(oldchar, repChar),
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
    document.Open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
    document.NewPage();
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    document.Close();
}
```

Comment: Save my time! Thank you!